# python pandas How to copy column values regarding an index column

Tags: python, pandas

*Note: the question was edited and extended as it originally lacked precision.
The first example introduces the question, but should only be considered as an introduction*

Having two datasets looking like:

```
idx  value other_columns  
1    7  
2    6  
3    5  

idx  value ...other_columns  
1    0  
2    0  
4    0
```

I'd like to copy the fist dataset values regarding the index column (and set NaN on non matching columns)

Obtaining this:

```
idx  value ...other_columns  
1    7  
2    6  
4    NaN
```

Regards

Edit:

Regarding my initial post, EdChum's answer was correct, but my question lacked precision.

The other_columns means i'd like to keep the other columns unchanged, an my goal is inserting values from dataset1 in dataset2.
More precise example:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'idx':[1,2,3], 'val':[7,6,5], 'other':[1,1,1]})  
df2= pd.DataFrame({'idx':[1,2,4], 'val':[0,0,0], 'other':[1,1,1]})  

 df1  
   idx  other val  
0    1      1   7  
1    2      1   6  
2    3      1   5  

 df2  
   idx  other  val  
0    1      7    0  
1    2      7    0  
2    4      7    0
```

I'd like to retrieve

```
   idx  other  val  
0    1      7    7  
1    2      7    6  
2    4      7    NaN
```

Which is a sub frame from Fuego's merge based anwser, but i don't see yet how to only keep the ['idx','val_x','other_y'] cols.

Comment: When you say index column, is it a column or is it really the index?

Comment: it's not the index, it is an attribute column whose values are distinct.

Comment: See the last portion of my answer

Comment: Now your desired output no longer matches your code you posted to create the dfs, please can you edit your question so it's correct

Comment: If you have more specific suggestion i'd be glad to, i try to keep consistance across the different answers as they are interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `merge` function of **panda** :

```
data = panda.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, on="idx", how="right")
```

The result you want will be the first column.

See the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) for more one the *how* parameter (set NaN, or take only left, right or both ...).

See ya !

**EDIT :**

I saw your edit and you wonder how to extract only the columns you want, but you just have to pass the columns you want to the merge :

```
data = panda.merge(df1[['idx', 'val']], df2.drop('val', axis=1), on="idx", how="right")
```

(don't worry, the drop command won't delete the column of df2, it will return a DataFrame without with column)

Comment: That will result in 4 rows not 3 like the OP's desired output

Comment: It depends on the how parameter, I edited to put "right" because I didn't see it was demanding only 3 rows. But I think he can understand this with the documentation.

Comment: It's still incomplete as there are clashes in the column values so that would introduce column_x and column_y additional columns so it's still an incomplete answer, I didn't downvote but your answer is still incomplete

Comment: Okey I understand :p Thx :)

Comment: This appears to be the answer, but actually myt test doesn't run: i get a key error on df1['idx','val'] expression.

Comment: Oh sorry it is because it's df1[['idx', 'val']], I edit my answer.

Comment: To complete the experience: regarding my question merge -> how="right" was the correct answer. For my real use, how="inner" (which is default) removes the non intersecting index rows (with val = NaN) : panda.merge(df1[['idx', 'val']], df2.drop('val', axis=1), on="idx")

Answer (score 3):

use `reindex`

```
In [142]:
df1.reindex(df2.index)

Out[142]:
     value  other_columns
idx                      
1      7.0            NaN
2      6.0            NaN
4      NaN            NaN
```

`reindex_like` also works:

```
In [143]:
df1.reindex_like(df2)

Out[143]:
     value  ...other_columns
idx                         
1      7.0               NaN
2      6.0               NaN
4      NaN               NaN
```

Or label-based index using `loc`:

```
In [144]:
df1.loc[df2.index]

Out[144]:
     value  other_columns
idx                      
1      7.0            NaN
2      6.0            NaN
4      NaN            NaN
```

If `idx` is really a column, then you need to call `set_index` first and then doc any of the above:

```
In [148]:
df1.set_index('idx').reindex(df2.set_index('idx').index).reset_index()

Out[148]:
   idx  value  other_columns
0    1    7.0            NaN
1    2    6.0            NaN
2    4    NaN            NaN
```

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi please explain as it looks to me that it's a reindexing question

Comment: His resulting dataframe looked like if he wants to merge. Maybe I was mistaken. Or maybe he didn't put his question properly.

Comment: Yes, i think i didn't detail the question enough, i'll edit it. Thanx for this quick and interesting answer.