# Python/Pandas: filter and organize the rows and columns of a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, reindex

I have two dataframes like df1, df2 below.
I would like to:

- **filter df1**: that is, remove rows and columns, so that it has the same index elements and columns as df2. The elements within the table for the columns and rows kept should be not be modified.
- In addition, I would like to **organize the rows and columns of this 'filtered' dataframe** so that it has rows and columns in the same order as df2.

Dataframe `df1` is:

| index | x_3 | x_1 | x_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 110 | 126 | 112 |
| 11 | 131 | 140 | 143 |
| 12 | 130 | 128 | 116 |
| 13 | 118 | 150 | 125 |
| 14 | 102 | 117 | 110 |
| 15 | 103 | 105 | 148 |
| 16 | 116 | 114 | 114 |
| 17 | 120 | 132 | 110 |

..and a second dataframe (`df2`) like:

| index | x_1 | x_2 | x_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 11 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 14 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 15 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 | 4 | 1 |

The final result would be df3, that is:

| index | x_1 | x_2 | x_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 126 | 112 | 110 |
| 11 | 140 | 143 | 131 |
| 14 | 117 | 110 | 102 |
| 15 | 105 | 148 | 103 |
| 16 | 114 | 114 | 116 |

Any insights?

Comment: Given that your index is unique, (i.e. doesn't have duplicates); since duplicates will break some approaches. Also when you say *'organize the columns of df3 like df1'* that's called *'df3 should have same column order as df1'*.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Pandas: replace values of one data frame with values of another data frame based on index and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133410/pandas-replace-values-of-one-data-frame-with-values-of-another-data-frame-based)

Comment: Related: [answer on `.reindex_like()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47961242/202229) also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260764/python-pandas-how-to-copy-column-values-regarding-an-index-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`.reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html)** to conform the `index` and `columns` of `df1` according to `index` and `columns` of `df2`:

```
df3 = df1.reindex_like(df2)
```

---

```
>>> df3

       x_1  x_2  x_3
index               
10     126  112  110
11     140  143  131
14     117  110  102
15     105  148  103
16     114  114  116
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.loc[df2.index, df2.columns]
```

Shubham's answer is quite pythonic. Using loc is also a simple way to go from first principles.